# Android Java: Trying to get this AES encryption library to work but it doesn't

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I'm trying to test this library

http://blog.cwill-dev.com/2012/10/09/encryption-between-javaandroid-and-php/

with this code

```
 ApiCrypter ApiCrypter = new ApiCrypter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);

    try {
        String encryptedRequest = ApiCrypter.bytesToHex(this.ApiCrypter.encrypt("hello world"));
        Toast.makeText(this, encryptedRequest, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In the example mentioned in the page

```
String encryptedRequest = ApiCrypter.bytesToHex(this.apiCrypter.encrypt(jsonParams.toString()));
```

But "apiCrypter" doesn't exist so I used the instance "ApiCrypter"

But the toast is not triggered at all. I tried to display the value in a TextView but it's empty too. Any help please?

Comment: You must be getting exception..Please check exception block.

Comment: *But "apiCrypter" doesn't exist so I used the instance "ApiCrypter"* The documentation assumes you have created an instance of `ApiCrypter` named `apiCrypter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
ApiCrypter ApiCrypter = new ApiCrypter();
```

with:

```
ApiCrypter apiCrypter = new ApiCrypter();
```

and then:

```
String encryptedRequest = ApiCrypter.bytesToHex(this.apiCrypter.encrypt(jsonParams.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both IV and key had to be 16 char length and they were shorter after fixing their length it worked fine